# Matrix conversion

Tags: unix, awk

How do I convert the following column matrix:

```
129
83
83
83
83
83
47
47
45
45
45
45
112
129
83
83
83
83
39
39
47
46
45
112
112
112
.
.
.
```

into this (using awk):

```
129
83
47
45
129
83
39
47
46
45
112
.
.
.
```

Basically, if I have any consecutive instances of a string, I would like to remove any copies. However, for a single instance of '112', I would like to remove it altogether, unless there are at least 2 or more consecutive instances of '112', then I would like to keep a copy of it. Thanks!

Comment: Did not downvote but did you try anything?

Comment: where is the matrix?

Comment: What's the desired result if the sequence contains `111 112 113 112 114 112 112`?  The first 112 should be removed; one of the third and fourth should be kept  because they're consecutive, but should the second 112 be kept or removed?  I think it is 'removed', but confirmation would be useful.

Comment: Hi Jon, the desired result would be 111 113 114 112

Answer (score 1):

I think handling the special case will be simpler with a combination of uniq/awk.

```
$ uniq -c file | awk '!/^1 112$/{print $2}'

129
83
47
45
129
83
39
47
46
45
112
```

Comment: Sure is (this is a filler).

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '($0==112&&++a[$0]==2)||($0!=112&&a[112]="a"&&p!=$0);{p=$0}' file
129
83
47
45
129
83
39
47
46
45
112
```

Comment: nice! this works very well :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use @karakfa's uniq+awk solution but just in case you want to see one way to do it all in awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
$0 == prev { cnt++; next }
{ prtPrev(); cnt=0; prev=$0 }
END { prtPrev() }
function prtPrev() {
    if ( (NR > 1) && !((prev == 112) && (cnt == 0)) ) {
        print prev
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
129
83
47
45
129
83
39
47
46
45
112
```

and an alternative inspired by [@JamesJones' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53601194/1745001):

```
$ cat tst.awk
$0 != prev { cnt = 0; prev = $0 }
{
    ++cnt
    if ( $0 == 112 ) { hit = (cnt == 2) }
    else             { hit = (cnt == 1) }
}
hit

$ awk -f tst.awk file
129
83
47
45
129
83
39
47
46
45
112
```

Fore!

```
$ awk '$0!=p{c=0;p=$0}{++c;if($0==112)h=(c==2);else h=(c==1)}h' file
129
83
47
45
129
83
39
47
46
45
112
```